# Setting Postfix IPTables rules safley

Tags: iptables, postfix

I'm IP Tables with these rules to allow postfix send and receive with OpenDKIM encryption, but are they too permissive?

I'd prefer to not be a relay bot, or be leaving my server vulnerable.

- I don't need POP3(110) because I'm not storing mail or managing mailboxes..
- No need for secure POP3(995) either.
- I don't need IMAP(143) because I'm not trying to access mail on a remote server.
- No need for secure IMAP(993) either.
- I do need SMTP(25) because I'm sending email,
- and I need secure SMTP(465) ---

Rules for OpenDKIM DNS lookups to verify txt signatures via port 53 are okay.

I'm currently using these rules for Postfix

```
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

INPUT 25 is intended to receive and initiate SMTP requests that may be promoted to 587.
NEW makes sense, is ESTABLISHED necessary?

INPUT/OUTPUT 465 was intended to receive SSL/SMTP but apparently its reassigned by IANA to a new service, so I'll remove it.

INPUT 587 is for TLS/SMTP, the encrypted email we want.
NEW makes sense, is ESTABLISHED necessary?

OUTPUT 25 is intended to send plain SMTP 
OUTPUT 587 is intended to send TLS/SMTP
NEW makes sense, but does ESTABLISHED?

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all cases, you need to allow `ESTABLISHED` traffic. Otherwise, any connection attempt will not get completed. This has to be allowed on all chains like `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` (if you are using it).

If you don't allow it, you need to **double** your rules for every allowed connection to be allowed in both directions (connection and its reply and by switching IPs/ports).

Also, one `ESTABLISHED` rule is enough for every chain. You don't need to have one for every IP/port. Here is an example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Okay, that helps. To save on RAM use can I go rule by rule?  um.. should my OUTPUT be -sports ?